"Addicted to Sexahol"?
I was watching an old episode of The Simpsons with Dr. Marvin Monroe. I was reminded of an expression which I could swear was from an episode of The Simpsons, but I cannot find any references to it. I’m not sure about the whole quote, but the ending is definitely part of it (I’m certain it was uttered by a male.)

It’s true, I’m a sexaholic; I’m addicted to sexahol.

Googling just various combinations of the end with other qualifiers comes up with nothing whatsoever, so I’m baffled because I did not just spontaneously invent the quote. I also tried the two most likely alternatives, Futurama and Family Guy, but still nothing.
Does anyone know what show/episode this quote is from?

There is one famous Homer Simpson quote that sounds like the one you are looking for:

It's true, I'm a rageoholic! I just can't get enough RAGEOHOL!

This is from S13E18 - I Am Furious Yellow. Source.
